# Joins In MySQL for fetching multiple tables data

Tags: mysql, join

[image]

I have two table user and follow. I want to write view such that it will fetch all details of particular user along with that two extra column as follower count and followee count alias.

eg. user id=11 then all details from user tables plus followcount 1 and followed count1

Comment: Why have you included all databases ? Include the one which you are using.

Comment: @agnes i am not including multiple db i want to fetch data from multiple tables

Comment: I am talking about your tags which you applied to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.userid, 
       u.name, 
       u.mobile, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   follow f 
        WHERE  f.followerid = u.userid) AS follower, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   follow f 
        WHERE  f.followeeid = u.userid) AS followee 
FROM   users u
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this is by using `JOIN` statements in your query:

example of how you can achieve your final result:

```
CREATE VIEW [Followers] AS 
SELECT a.name, a.email, a.mobile, COUNT(SELECT COUNT(followerID) FROM follow WHERE followerID = a.userid), COUNT(SELECT COUNT(followeeID) FROM follow WHERE followeeID = a.userid) FROM users a INNER JOIN follow b ON b.followerID = a.userid
```

Comment: above solution gives onlu users details but i need count of users follower and followee in same query